# On adminform save gives an error : Call to a member function load() on boolean

Tags: magento-1.9, error, adminform, save

Here is the form that i am using in admin form:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save'),
        'method' => 'post',
        ));

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    $helper = Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany');
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('display', array('legend' => $helper->__('Select Social Icons'),
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide'));

    $fieldset->addField('facebook', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'facebook',
        'label' => $helper->__('Facebook'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('google', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'google',
        'label' => $helper->__('Google'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('twitter', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'twitter',
        'label' => $helper->__('Twitter'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('linkedin', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'linkedin',
        'label' => $helper->__('Linkedin'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('yelp', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'yelp',
        'label' => $helper->__('Yelp'),
        ));


    if (Mage::registry('optfirst_reviewmycompany')) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->getData());
    }

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

And here is the my s**ave action method** in **controller**:

```
public function saveAction()
    {

    //$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
if ( $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams() ) {

    print_r($data);

    $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
    $model = Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review')->load(1);
    //$model = Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review');
    print_r($model->getData());

    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    try {
        if ( $id ) {
            $model->load($id);
        }
        $model->addData($data);
        //saves data
        $model->save();

        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('Data was saved'));

        $this->_getSession()->setFormData(false);

        if ( $this->getRequest()->getParam('back') ) {
            $params = array('id' => $model->getId());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', $params);
        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/list');
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        if ( $model && $model->getId() ) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array(
                'id' => $model->getId()
            ));
        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/new');
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

And following is my **modal**:

```
class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model_Review extends        Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
   {
    public function _construct()
      {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review');
      }
  }
```

And i am posting my model configuration as follos:

```
<models>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
            <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>optfirst_reviewmycompany_resources</resourceModel>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany_resources>
            <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model_Resources</class>
            <entities>
                <review>
                    <table>optfirst_reviewmycompany_icons</table>
                </review>
            </entities>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany_resources>
    </models>
```

Now issue when i save form in admin its generates an error as follows:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on boolean in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-new\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php
>   on line 225

**So how I can solve this error so it will save my data to database**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were missing the **resource model**

```
class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model_Resource_Review extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review'', 'primarykey');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already defined that, sorry i didn't mentioned it earlier.. is there any issue with my config file? @Qaisar Satti

Comment: What will be my primarykey in current situation?
I have defined as like this: $this->_init('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review', 'id_optfirst_reviewmycompany');

Comment: yes it is correct. did you define models in `<global></global>` tag

Comment: Yes i did in global..

Comment: Now i got this error...
Call to a member function beginTransaction()

Comment: @Xabby look this solution http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73296/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-begintransaction-on-boolean-in-var-www